# Passing div attribute in props give 503

Tags: vue.js

I am using Trustpilot to make components, which uses different widget on same pages, so every template-id is different. Following is my code but I do not see anything expect TrustPilot logo but if I remove `props` and give the provided template-id, it works.

What am I doing wrong?

TheWidget.vue

```
 <div class="trustpilot-widget" 
    data-locale="en-GB" 
    data-template-id="'${tid}'"
    data-businessunit-id=""/omitted because of security  
    data-style-height="20px"  
    data-style-width="100%"> 
    <a href="https://uk.trustpilot.com/review/believeloans.com" target="_blank">Trustpilot</a>
    </div>
<script>
export default {
    props: ['tid'],

    created() {
        //Code omitted
    }
}
</script>
```

Home.vue

```
<TheWidget tid="09765291018" />
```

Comment: Do your dev tools say anything?  You're binding your `tid` to `data-template-id` incorrectly.  It should be `:data-template-id="tid"`  And your component can't have a space in it i.e. `<The Widget>` should either be `the-widget` or `TheWidget`.

Comment: @StevenB. The space was my mistake i fixed it. Vue Dev Tools does give me a tid

Comment: I would say there is an issue somewhere else then because the provided code works fine except for the binding of tid to your div's property.  Maybe in a lifecycle method.

Comment: It worked! But I wonder why wasn't my binding working? Also i tried to make height dynamic but I get error in console. `Error on bootstrap:Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined` where I am passing height as `height="40px"` @StevenB.

Comment: Wonder no longer ~ https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes